# textbox doesn't show massage c#

Tags: c#, timer, textbox

I just want to create WindowsFormsApp that timer run when program start
and then textbox2 will show text

> event run

EDIT

timer tick but

> textBox2.Text = "event run"; << Doesn't Run

```
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer myTimer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        myTimer.Elapsed += myEvent;
        myTimer.AutoReset = true;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;

        textBox1.Text = "Timer start";
    }

    private void myEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "event run";
    }
```

}

Can anyone help? Thanks!

EDIT

> I add myTimer.Start(); and breakpoint hit in myEvent but textbox
>   doesn't show massage

Answer (score 2):

You did not start the timer `myTimer.Start();` that's why timer is not working.

```
 myTimer.Interval = 1000;
            myTimer.Start();
```

And for more details, refer to [this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/timer-cs.htm).

Comment: Thanks,Timer tick now ,but line TextBox2.Text = "event run"; doesn't run

Comment: Make sure your textbox is visible and you may test by putting default value(random value) in your textbox on page load or on designer. Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: textbox is visible and i tried to set value in textbox when page load.it show value that i set,but it still doesn't show " event run " (ps. don't have any query)

Comment: put your value in     if (!IsPostBack)

    {. . . . . . . . . } on page load

Answer (score 1):

You have not called `Start` method like this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
    myTimer.Elapsed += myEvent;
    myTimer.AutoReset = true;
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
```

> myTimer.Start();

```
    textBox1.Text = "Timer start";
}
```

You have just enabled timer and all but you need to start it also using `Start` method.

Also there is no need for `static` keyword as then you cannot access it in `Form_Load` which is not static

Comment: Thanks.but  I tried to add myTimer.Start(); and It didn’t work. :(

Comment: breakpoint hit inside event ,but i don't know why textbox doesn't show massage.

Comment: Make sure that your textbox is placed correctly inside the form and is visible

Comment: Can you do a refresh on textbox like this textBox2.Refresh();